# Fixed bottom bar with min-height

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand the trick in https://www.google.com/.

The bottom bar has `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` but if you minimize window's height it stays ("stacks") under the logo/input.

Of course this is something doable with js but is it with pure CSS?
My question is is there any CSS trick that can create this "stack effect", if so how can this be done?

I tried to understand if the `<span>Google Logo</span> <div>Bottom bar</div>` does the trick but I guess no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean way of doing this is to set a bottom margin on the body that is equal to the footer height.

Here's your css:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <article>Lorem ipsum...</article>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example of this approach: http://mystrd.at/data/sticky_footer.html

Answer (score 2):

It's because they set a `padding-bottom` value equal to the height of the footer in order to displace it.

```
.content {
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

See.. `padding-bottom:35px` = `height:35px`

```
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes. My question is although it has absolute/bottom 0, it is invisible when you resize the window in (let's say) 300px height as if . But for more than 485px it starts "moving" down. Is it because #viewport has `position: relative;` ?

Comment: Interesting approach as well. Thanks.